# Binary search boundary cases

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, binary-search

Recently  doing some questions on leetcode but a [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/search-in-rotated-sorted-array/) confuses me.

It requires you to search a number in a rotate sorted array. I understand the **basic concept** of binary search is to divide something by 2 so it will be O(log n).

When I read the [answer](https://www.programcreek.com/2014/06/leetcode-search-in-rotated-sorted-array-java/) online, 2 **questions** just popped out.

1.what is the point of adding the equal sign in the second `if` condition (`nums[mid] >= nums[start]`). The question stated that all the number will be unique. There is no way to be equal number. 
2. The solution also mention we need to distinguish which direction has the array rotated. What is the reason behind?

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
class Solution {
    public int search(int[] nums, int target) {
        if (nums == null)
            return -1;

        int start = 0;
        int end = nums.length - 1;

        while (start <= end) {
            int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;

            if(nums[mid] == target) {
                return mid;
            }

            if(nums[mid] >= nums[start]){
                if(nums[start] <= target && nums[mid] > target){
                    end = mid - 1;
                }else{
                    start = mid + 1;
                }
            }else{
                if(nums[mid] < target && nums[end] >= target){
                    start = mid + 1;
                }else{
                    end = mid - 1;
                }
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: *1. There is no way to be equal number.* That is incorrect. There is **one** easy way. And once I tell you, you will kick yourself. `mid` **could** equal `start`. That is you compare it to itself. Guaranteed to be equal. *2. Why we need to distinguish rotation direction* Look at when you set `end = mid - 1;` based on your nested `if` **chain**. Notice when you don't set `end` you set `start`. That's what that is doing. If you didn't need to handle rotation, you could eliminate one level of nesting.

Comment: For the first question, sounds like I need to set  ```>=```  every time or I can just set ```>, == , <``` separately. 


For the second question, checking the rotation seems to be needed when you need do check the current element falls into specific range?